# how to set custom example in @ApiResponse in swagger

Tags: swagger

I am using swagger 2.9.2 and want to put some custom example in the response and my code is as follows

```
@ApiResponse(code=200,
    message="fetch test lists",
    examples=@Example(
        value = @ExampleProperty(
            mediaType = "application/json",
            value = "{testingId: 1234, testingName = Testing Name}"
        )
    )
)
```

But getting response example value as

```
[
    {}
]
```

Kindly suggest solution to get my expected response as

```
[
    {
    "testingId": "1234",
    "testingName" = "Testing Name"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please let me know, if you have found solution for this